# Schannel protocol registry setting override ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol values?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, servicepointmanager

I am creating a WCF application in which I am setting the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to accept TLS1.2.
I will also be creating the SChannel service registry keys as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-schannel-protocols-in-the-windows-registry) to disable all client / server protocols other than TLS1.2 (will set Enabled = 0).

I understand that the SChannel setting creates an OS level setting.
I was wondering if in my code I explicitly set
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`
would it override the OS setting and allow TLS1.1 connections?

I got confused because of the statements here -
[If you want to configure security with the registry, don't specify a security protocol value in your code; doing so overrides the registry setting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-security-via-the-windows-registry)

[This update will not change the behavior of applications that are manually setting the secure protocols instead of passing the default flag.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi)

Edit 1: I am using .Net v4.7.

Comment: In fact, this is also related to the framework you use. If your application targets .NET 4.7.x, no matter how you set the registry key, you are actually using "SystemDefaultTlsVersions".

Comment: @Dingpeng - thanks! Any documentation pointers for that? I have been searching for days for such clear documentation.

Comment: You can refer to this link, hope it can help you:https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4675